# Rust - Call functions from a c lib under windows with .dll file

Tags: rust, ffi, abi

I'm working on a project that need to call a C project shared lib in Windows.

Suppose I have the `my-math.dll` file under rust src folder. I already add `libc` crate in `Cargo.toml` and following is my `main.rs` code:

```
extern crate libc;

#[link(name = "my-math")]
extern {    

}
fn main() {
    
}
```

When I tried to build the project, it came with the error  `note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'my-math.lib'`

Seems the `#[link(name="my-math")]` converted to `my-math.lib` automatically. But I only have the `.dll` file. Is there anyway to switch to `dll` file instead of `lib` file.

I don't want to use the header file with `bindgen` crate for some special reasons.

Comment: What happens when you add ".dll" to the name of your link attribute? So it would be `#link[name = "my-math.dll")]`

Comment: same error but with the name `my-math.dll.lib`

Comment: It seems [that](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-call-functions-from-dll/10156/8) should be the solution.